# Ethernet cut off wifi and almost freeze Debian stretch

Tags: debian, wifi, ethernet

I am running a freshly installed Debian stretch fully updated.
Wifi is working well alone.
When plugging in an Ethernet cable the laptop (Dell latitude) slows down dramatically, freezes for at least a minute and laptop seems being working hard.
Also the wifi is automatically disabled (no wifi connection are visible anymore in the network-manager widget).

I would like to solve both issues:

- avoiding the laptop to freeze
- get wifi and ethernet to work simultaneously

I hope I can avoid reinstalling for that. 
Maybe a few packages have been missed during installation. 
Note that I install while an ethernet cable was connected.
Note also that I install the package "firmware-iwlwifi" afterward.

I also tried to modifiy the file /etc/network/interfaces by commenting the line:

auto lo

which didn't help..